# Problems with multisite on wordpress when migrate it

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

well here is my problem: I created a wordpress multisite and it works in localhost, where I tried to migrate it to a remote server and I am having a strange problem.

First, I have installed a new wordpress site and I have activated the multisite option, modifying the .htaccess and wp-config.php files, after that I have copied all files of the site except wp-config.php and .htaccess, and finally I changed all referenced urls and domains on the database (Of course, imported before).

Well the url is http://sanmigueladoratrices.com/ I can see the principal site that is the same of http://sanmigueladoratrices.com/inicio but I cant see the other two themes, /matriculados and /nomatriculados else I cannot see the admin site, /wp-admin, I dont know why and I need help.

Really thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved. No one helped me but maybe that post can help someone.

The problem was that mod_rewrite was failing so you have to activate it correctly.